# Take selected icon list values into an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to make a password generator using icons. It's designed so that you click on any number of icons in a list and the hex code is put into an input box. Two important bits:

- The hex codes appear in the input box the same no matter what order you selected the icons in.
- You can toggle and untoggle the icons.

Here is my code so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/uvzb8a6s/1/

HTML

```
<input id="pass">
<ul id="icons">
<li class="icon">&#9824;</li>
<li class="icon">&#9742;</li>
<li class="icon">&#9743;</li>
<li class="icon">&#9744;</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#icons li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "active" ); 
    $('#pass').text('#icons li');
});
```

How do I get the value of all active li's listed into the input box, something like this (if I had clicked icon three and then icon one:

```
&#9824;&#9743;
```

Comment: Without save the order of the icons, is not a safe method to store a password.

Comment: @Vixed How come? I think would generate a strong password

Comment: Let's imagine a keyboard with only number, i can set a password like **2214473** now imagine that your icon are 10 (0 to 9) and try to write the  same password. May I click two or more times the same number? Will you store it with the order I want if you use **pass.text('#icons li');** ?  Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select `li` elements that has active class with `li.active`
- Get their texts with [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text) method.
- Set the input's value with [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) method.

Additionally:

- To get `html entity string` instead of characters inside the input, you can replace each character with its `entity string` by making use of [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method. See the Stringify button in the example.

```js
$('#icons li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#pass").val($("#icons li.active").text());
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("#pass").val($("#pass").val().replace(/(.)/g, function(char) {
    return "&#" + char.charCodeAt() + ";";
  }));
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pass">
<button>Stringify</button>
<ul id="icons">
  <li class="icon">&#9824;</li>
  <li class="icon">&#9742;</li>
  <li class="icon">&#9743;</li>
  <li class="icon">&#9744;</li>
</ul>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/uvzb8a6s/21/)

Comment: I will make this is answered when I can. I don't suppose you know how to display the code rather than the icon in the text box, i.e ```&#9824;```

Comment: @Jimmy, Only way I could think would be to use a lookup containing the characters and their html entity names, and replace the characters with their string equivalents manually. See the updated snippet.

Comment: I realized it would be more sustainable to make use of `.charCodeAt()` instead of a lookup object. This way you wouldn't need to manually maintain an object of possible characters. So I updated the example to use `.charCodeAt()` and got rid of the lookup object.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/uvzb8a6s/9/

```
$('#icons li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  var oldPass = $('#pass').val();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    oldPass = oldPass + $(this).html();
  } else {
    var textToRemove = $(this).html();
    oldPass = oldPass.replace(textToRemove, '');
  }
  alert(oldPass);
  $('#pass').val(oldPass);
});
```

This code also consider the sequence in which you click on icons to select them as well as deselect them.